# ibtool error code 255 on building every new project in Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Tags: xcode

Building working well on old projects, But for every new projects building I see this error:

```
CompileXIB newTest/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
    cd /Users/vahid/Documents/xCode/newTest
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --errors --warnings --notices --module newTest --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/vahid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newTest-gnosuvtbubvrbucxatowufbvkvyd/Build/Intermediates/newTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/newTest.build/LaunchScreen-PartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/vahid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newTest-gnosuvtbubvrbucxatowufbvkvyd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/newTest.app/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.nib /Users/vahid/Documents/xCode/newTest/newTest/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart mac without check `Reopen windows when logging back in` option fixed problem.

A simple reboot sometimes will save a lot of times. LOL